# How can I get the topbar on all of my monitors?

Tags: 21.04, taskbar

I need to get the topbar with the date and hour on all my monitors. I try to use compiz but I don't know how to do it, ideas?
This taskbar:

[image: System Task Bar]

Comment: Ive tried with multiple monitor but its only moving between monitors the extensions that Ive installed, is there a way to duplicate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install the Gnome Shell extension [Multi Monitors Add-On](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/921/multi-monitors-add-on/) by spin83 to have the top bar on all monitors. The easiest and safest way to do so is to install the package `gnome-shell-extension-multimonitors` using Snap store or the command `sudo apt install gnome-shell-extension-multimonitors`. Enable the extension using the Extensions preferences tool. Install that first using Snap store or with the command `sudo apt install gnome-shell-extension-multimonitors`.

Comment: Yeah, it worked but it is bugging some icons, thank you anyways.